# How can I return a value for a function from inside a function inside the function I wish to return

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wish to be able to return and end a function from inside a function inside that function. Just typing return inside the function will return for that function instead of the one I'm trying to return for.

```
function iWannaEscapeThis() {
     function someSideFunction() {
         //need to return iWannaEscapeThis here somehow
    }
}
```

Comment: read basics of JS, ES and etc. and develop logical thinking abilities. it's commons, if You cannot think about such simple things, so I don't think that You'll be good developer.

Comment: Do you need to return iwannaescapethis, or you want to end iwannaescapethis function?

Comment: The answer is either "it's impossible" or a simple `return` statement. It really depends on how `somesidefunction` is called. Maybe a duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/218196).

Comment: If you want this to be a generic escape mechanism were you could return from any sub function within `iWannaEscapeThis`, you could use a custom Exception and trap for this.

Answer (score 3):

You need to call it main `function` and `return` it

```js
function iwannaescapethis() {
     function somesidefunction() {
         return 'from inside'
    }
    return somesidefunction();
}
console.log(iwannaescapethis())
```

**Async function**

```js
async function iwannaescapethis() {
     async function somesidefunction() {
         let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => resolve("from inner"), 2000)
         });
         return await promise;
    }
    let x = await somesidefunction()
    return x;
}
(async function(){
  let res = await iwannaescapethis()
  console.log(res)
})()
```

Comment: Remove async, await words from second function and simply `return new Promise...`. Cause async/await is syntactic sugar on promises. So when Your method returns promise it means that method can be await-ed

Comment: @num8er I can't get what you mean. I will be thankful if you give me the correct version of my code

Comment: @num8er So what!? Why should he remove it? It does the same.

Comment: @Amiratak88 I did not say that he is wrong. He asked me to review his answer. So my opinion is that: It does the same, but it wraps already written promise inside of unnecessary extra promise. in fact there is just 1 promise inside `somesidefunction`, wrapping in extra async/await implicitly puts it inside another promise.
If You don't like it write You own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Return the nested function:

```js
function iwannaescapethis() {
  function somesidefunction() {
    return "sideFunction";
  }
  return somesidefunction();
}
console.log(iwannaescapethis());
```

Comment: but what if `somesidefunction` is asynchronous?

Comment: You could `async/await` it.

Comment: so then extend Your answer with such situations too. with async/await, with promises, with callbacks, with `async.waterfall`

Comment: @num8er  There is no mention of `async` code in the Op's question.

Comment: @num8er I have added async part in answer not sure its right way. Please check it. And correct if i am wrong

Comment: @MaheerAli but funny that question author not responding to answers. Seems like he is not interested to learn from answers to his issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use exceptions for doing this, but a big warning it's not advised you use exceptions for flow control too often.

But if you really do need this feature, here is an example.

```js
class ReturnException extends Error {
  constructor (value) { super(); this.value = value; }
};


function thisIsTheOuterFunction() {
  try {
    function someSubFunction() {
      function someOtherSubFunction() {
        throw new ReturnException("The answer is 42");
      }
      someOtherSubFunction();
    }
    someSubFunction();
  } catch (e) {
    if (e instanceof ReturnException) {
      return e.value;
    } else throw e;
  }
}

console.log(thisIsTheOuterFunction());
```